# The order of which time complexity is higher, 3 ^ log(n) or n ^ 3?

Tags: time-complexity

Which one has a higher order time complexity:

- $n ^ 3$
- $3 ^ {\log n}$

I know that an exponential time order is higher than polynomials. However, it uses a logarithmic power which is low for a large n, while n^3 or more could remain still high, not?

Comment: Are you talking about which of the two functions grows faster, or which is easier to compute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer easily follows from the identity $3^{\log n} = n^{\log 3}$. Whether or not $\log 3 < 3$ depends on the basis of the logarithm.